# Prism: Prevent executing a command in duplicate views using IActiveAware?

Tags: .net, silverlight, prism, command

I have a Silverlight application that has three regions that will host the same Views.  What I want to know is, how may I create a zoom control for each of the views, without zooming all of the views (assuming the zoom action is using Prism Commands).  Would IActiveAware be the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, to determine the active view IActiveAware is proabably the way to go. You can find information about a usage scenario in this thread:
http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=54953

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Damian